# A fixed div within container IE8 problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pageYOffset Scrolling and Animation in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286162/pageyoffset-scrolling-and-animation-in-ie8)

In my previous question:

[A fixed div within a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888317/a-fixed-div-within-a-container/11888396#11888396)

The answer and solution was:

http://jsfiddle.net/BbAck/3

After some further testing the problem I am having is that it won't work in IE8.

What am I missing here and where should I be looking to fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286162/pageyoffset-scrolling-and-animation-in-ie8

Comment: @Ashirvad Singh is correct, IE8 does not recognize the pageYOffset for height meaning you calculation always turns up false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
yOffset = window.pageYOffset;
```

by:

```
yOffset = $(window).scrollTop();
```

And make sure your page has html5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BbAck/4/